HTTP POST requests with standard authorization
I've a pipeline created in azure where it has only one file azure-pipelines.yml
Through postman I want to send HTTP POST requests to this pipeline with standard authorization. I want a global authorization method and not PAT.

What API do you want to send with POST? Do you want to use the POST API to trigger the pipeline? What do you mean about "a global authorization method"?

Yes it's to trigger a pipeline. Global authorization is once authorizing is done it can be used by anyone so they don't require azure access.

You can try to set the authentication credentials as team shared variables on Postman. See my answer below for more information. @Amrutha k

As far as I know, every time to open a new session to call an API on Postman, users need to manually select the authentication type and credentials on the Authentication tab.
You can save the credentials as environment variables on Postman, then you can directly use the variables by referencing the variable names ({{varName}}) on the Authentication tab.
You also can reference the Postman documentation "Work with environments as a team in Postman" to manage and share the environment variables in a team.

